# How to transfer dependancy jars / files to azure storage from linux?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-storage

I am trying to use azure spark. To run my job, I need to copy my dependancy jar and files to storage. i have created a storage and container. Could you please guide me how to access Azure storage from my linux machine so as to copy date from/to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't state your restrictions (e.g., command line, programmatically, gui), here are a few options:

1. If you have access to a recent Python interpreter on your Linux machine, you can use blobxfer (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blobxfer), which can transfer entire directories of files into and out of Azure blob storage.
2. Use Azure cross-platform cli (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/) which has functionality to transfer files one at a time into or out of Azure storage.
3. Directly invoke Azure storage calls via Azure storage SDKs programmatically. There are SDKs available in a variety of languages along with REST.

Comment: thanks for the help. I waned to transfer from local machine via console . It worded